# How would i change it so it happens to all Entities and not just Players Minecraft Forge Modding

Tags: java, minecraft, entities, minecraft-forge

I want it so my swords will effect all entities, not just players (rn it is only players) How would i change my code so that if it hits an entity there is a chance that the effect will happen instead of having it 100% and only on players? Here is my code:

```
@SubscribeEvent
    public static void swordEffects(TickEvent.WorldTickEvent event) {
        if (Minecraft.getInstance().player != null) {
            if (Minecraft.getInstance().player.inventory.getCurrentItem().equals(ModItems.BLACK_IRON_SWORD)) {
                Minecraft.getInstance().player.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.SLOWNESS, 3600, 3));
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the separation of game logic to the client and server sides.

Explore this: https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.15.x/concepts/sides/

In your code, you take a player from Minecraft.getInstance().player, it's a instance of the main player on client. This means that this code can only be run from the client side => server knows nothing about the effect application => effect won't really be applied.

To apply the effect to the entity which hold a sword in hand, use override of `inventoryTick` method in the class of your sword's item.
`Entity` instance, which hold sword in their inventory, exists in arguments of `inventoryTick`.
Check that the sword is in hand of entity and give the effect.

```java
public class CustomSword extends SwordItem {

    @Override
    public void inventoryTick(ItemStack stack, World worldIn, Entity entityIn, int itemSlot, boolean isSelected) {
        if(isSelected && entityIn instanceof LivingEntity)
            ((LivingEntity) entityIn).addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.SLOWNESS, 3600, 3));
    }

    ...
}
```

Name of inventoryTick  method may be different depending on mappings. I used `mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20201028-1.16.3'`

Comment: i added that in and edited a little to fit my needs
```
@Override
    public void inventoryTick(ItemStack stack, World worldIn, Entity entityIn, int itemSlot, boolean isSelected) {
        assert Minecraft.getInstance().player != null;
        if (Minecraft.getInstance().player.inventory.getCurrentItem().equals(ModItems.BLACK_IRON_SWORD)) {
                if(isSelected && entityIn instanceof LivingEntity)
                    ((LivingEntity) entityIn).addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.POISON, 3600, 3));
            }
        }```
It still doesn't work tho.

Comment: `Minecraft` is client only class, do not use it at server side